# Confused in this probability example.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to find the probability $\ P(\overline A +\overline B)$

I have $\ P(A) = 0.42$ ;
$\ P(A * B) = 0.40$ ;
$\ P(A + B) = 0.64$
I calculated $\ P(B) = 0.62$
When my teacher solved it he was direct $\ P(\overline A +\overline B) = 1 - P(A*B) = 1-0.40 = 0.60$

I don't think this is the right solution. According to me:
[image]

The outer space should be counted twice so:

$\ P(\overline A +\overline B) = 1 - P(A) + 1 - P(B) = 1-0.42 + 1-0.62 = 0.96$

Which solution is right?

Comment: "The outer space should be counted twice" No. What makes you think this?

Comment: From the image you can see that there are two different color lines outside A and B, that's what makes me think like this.

Comment: Sorry but your reason is not very explicit (probably the main reason why you are lost, if you ask me). So... for the same P(A) and for P(B) = 0.52 instead of P(B) = 0.62, your answer would have been?

Comment: `1-0.42+1-0.52=0.98`???

Comment: I think I understand it now. So for $\ P(\overline A + B) = 1 - P(A\B) = 1-0.02 = 0.98$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is correct but maybe the "long" way of doing things will make the solution more obvious.

P(A'U B') = P(A') + P(B') - P(A'∩ B')
If you draw a Venn Diagram to depict A'∩ B' you will see that it is equivalent to (A U B)'
So, P(A'U B') = P(A') + P(B') -P((A U B)') = (1-0.42)+(1-0.62) - (1-0.64)
=0.58+0.38-0.36=0.60

Comment: Please check the last comment on the question. Is that solution right?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) to learn how to typeset math here.

Comment: Your solution assumes that the sets A and B are mutually exclusive which is false since P(A*B) is not zero. Venn Diagrams help to see the solution a lot clearer. You want to find P(A¯+B¯). Can you shade the corresponding area? If you do then you will realize that everywhere except the intersection would be shaded. Hence your teacher's solution of 1-P(A∩B). Hope this helps

Comment: Actually the Last comment is about $\ P(\overline A +B)$ not $\ P(\overline A +\overline B)$. I tried something else to see if I can get it right. So I am asking if  $\ P(\overline A +B) = 0.98$

Comment: Didn't do it your way but I got the same answer